# Getting application crash during opening a local csv file with size more than 2Mb on UIWebView in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, csv, uiwebview

Here ,I put my code. its working fine for file size less than 2 mb. Anybody have any idea please help me.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     NSURL *fileUrl=  [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"userdata"] withExtension:@".csv"];
     [webV loadRequest:[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl]];}
```

Application crash with the error : "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue".
Thanks in advance

Comment: How you resolved this ..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have zombie objects turned on?

Another thought would be do you have any loops creating and destroying objects?
The memory won't be released until the run loop it is in is allowed to complete or you include the code in an 
[@autoreleasepool block](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't have any loops creating and destroying objects. Zombie objects need to b turn off or on? and i tried with @autoreleasepool block. but its not working for me.